# Dynamically change the page title in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1

I've opened my the 1column.phtml file and I'm trying to capture dynamically the Meta Title of the product using the following snippet:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

Then I'm trying to put it in the  tags of the same page:

```
<title><?php $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?><title>
```

but no lack...

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achive ... can you please add a more detailed description?

Comment: If you go to Catalog -> Manage Products then select a product and then go to Meta Information, there is a Meta Title field there. I want to be able to capture that value in the page using code, and put that value as a page title. I'm using this code: $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); but when I'm putting it in the <title> tag in the page I see no difference.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you forget the echo ?

```
<title><?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?><title>
```

Comment: aahhh.. sorry... I was a typo. The echo was there I forgot to include it here